# how to groupby in complicated condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this

```
     A    B    C
0    1    7    a
1    2    8    b
2    3    9    c
3    4   10    a
4    5   11    b
5    6   12    c
```

I would like to get groupby result (key=column C) below;

```
    A    B
d  12   36
```

"d" means  a or b ,

so I would like to groupby only with "a" and "b".

and then put together as "d".

when I sum up with all the key elements then drop, it consume much time....

Comment: So you want to drop rows with `c` in column `C`?

Comment: thank you for early reply .yes ! I want to drop c in colulmn C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `pandas` `where` to transform the C column so that where it was `a` or `b` becomes `d` and then you can groupby the transformed column and do the normal summary on it, and if rows with `c` is not desired, you can simply drop it after the summary:

```
df_sum = df.groupby(df.C.where(~df.C.isin(['a', 'b']), "d")).sum().reset_index()

df_sum
#   C   A   B
#0  c   9   21
#1  d   12  36

df_sum.loc[df_sum.C == "d"]

#   C   A   B
#1  d   12  36
```

To see more clearly how the `where` clause works:

```
df.C.where(~df.C.isin(['a','b']), 'd')

# 0    d
# 1    d
# 2    c
# 3    d
# 4    d
# 5    c
# Name: C, dtype: object
```

It acts like a replace method and replace `a` and `b` with `d` which will be grouped together when passed to `groupby` function.